# Can a struts 1 action mapping call struts 2 action

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts

My existing application is built using struts 1 framework and I m adding new business components into it using struts 2 framework . Enabling both in single application is successful but don't have any clue to call struts 2 action from within strut 1. 
Is it really possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A link is a link, it doesn't matter how the link's server-side action is implemented.

As long as you can generate the correct URL, you're fine.